# AngularJS: Load data json in controller from factory

Tags: angularjs, json, controller, factory, angular-promise

I can't load the data in controller, return undefined.

I have this factory service:

```
app.factory('factoryLlamada', function($http,$q) { return{
    cargar: function(archivo) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(archivo).success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}});
```

And this controller:

```
app.controller('ctrlProducts', function(factoryLlamada) {
    this.saludo = 'Hola'; //this work's
    factoryLlamada.cargar('prueba.json').then(function(data) {
        this.datos = data;
        console.dir(data);  //return json object (ok)
        console.dir(datos); //return undefined
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Se ha producido un error: '+error);
    });
});
```

I don't know which is the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` inside the callback function does not refer to the controller.

Write instead:

```
app.controller('ctrlProducts', function(factoryLlamada) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.saludo = 'Hola'; //this work's

    factoryLlamada.cargar('prueba.json').then(function(data) {
        vm.datos = data;
        console.dir(data);  //return json object (ok)
        console.dir(vm.datos);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Se ha producido un error: '+error);
    });
});
```

And by the way, in the factory you don't have to use `$q` promises. Just reuse the promise returned by `$http.get` and the code will be much concise:

```
app.factory('factoryLlamada', function($http) { return{
    cargar: function(archivo) {
        return $http.get(archivo);
    }
}});
```

And retrieve the data like this:

```
factoryLlamada.cargar('prueba.json').then(function(response) {
    // data is in response.data
});
```

Comment: That wont work since he states in the comments already this.saludo="Hola" works

Comment: The `this` from `this.saludo` refers to the controller as it's outside of the callback. But that's not the case for `this.datos`.

Comment: This answer is correct.  You have to be careful using 'this' rather than $scope.  In this case 'this' in the nested function is not the same as the 'this' in the controller.